# How to check if decimal is valid value in Teradata

Tags: teradata

How to check if the given decimal is valid. I usually do a case statement like below to check if column is invalid or NULL then set it to 0 else take it as it is:

```
case when decimal_column is NULL or decimal_column NOT BETWEEN -999999999999 AND 999999999999 then 0 else decimal_column end
```

Can anyone please let me know if the above query looks correct

Thanks

Comment: What defines "valid"?  How is your column defined?  You're not casting it, so is it already defined as decimal?  If your column is not defined as decimal, Rob's answer should work perfectly.

Comment: @Andrew : My column is already decimal and i need to check if my decimal_column contains any non numeric data.

Comment: If a column is defined as DECIMAL any invalid data will return a conversion error while loading.

Answer (score 0):

In Teradata 14.10 or greater, the `TO_NUMBER()` function can be used.

```
SELECT TO_NUMBER({decimal column})
  FROM {table};
```

If the conversion to number failed, `TO_NUMBER()` returns NULL. See the SQL Functions,Operators, Expressions and Predicates manual for more details.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `trycast`. Something like ..:

```
trycast(trim(col1)) as DECIMAL (XX,Y))
```

From TD-Doku: *TRYCAST takes a string and tries to cast it to a data type specified after the AS keyword (similar to CAST). If the conversion fails, TRYCAST returns a NULL instead of failing.*